# Disable Iframe Reload in FullScreen

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have the follow code, for make a IFRAME go to FullScreen with button click,

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#container .button');
button.addEventListener('click', fullscreen);
// when you are in fullscreen, ESC and F11 may not be trigger by keydown listener. 
// so don't use it to detect exit fullscreen
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  console.log('key press' + e.keyCode);
});
// detect enter or exit fullscreen mode
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', fullscreenChange);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenChange);
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenChange);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', fullscreenChange);

function fullscreen() {
  // check if fullscreen mode is available
  if (document.fullscreenEnabled || 
    document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || 
    document.mozFullScreenEnabled ||
    document.msFullscreenEnabled) {
    
    // which element will be fullscreen
    var iframe = document.querySelector('#container iframe');
    // Do fullscreen
    if (iframe.requestFullscreen) {
      iframe.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      iframe.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (iframe.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      iframe.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (iframe.msRequestFullscreen) {
      iframe.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
  else {
    document.querySelector('.error').innerHTML = 'Your browser is not supported';
  }
}

function fullscreenChange() {
  if (document.fullscreenEnabled ||
       document.webkitIsFullScreen || 
       document.mozFullScreen ||
       document.msFullscreenElement) {
    console.log('enter fullscreen');
  }
  else {
    console.log('exit fullscreen');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="top-left">
    <button class="button">Ver Ecrã Completo</button>
  </div>

      <iframe src="http://google.pt" Title="google" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
```

I pretend disable refreshing/reload when I go to fullscreen and vice versa, how I missing and how can I make it?

ps: I have added google as example.
note: The Iframe to be added as SWF and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I forget remove the follow code on primary code:

> var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
> iframe.src = iframe.src;